# Minimum size that matches aspect ratio

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I need to find the *minimum* size that has an aspect ratio of exactly (or within 0.001) some value. Are there any quick math tricks or framework tricks for doing this?

Here's the pseudo code for the current *bad* idea I had running in `O(n^2)`:

```
epsilon = 0.001;

from x = 1 to MAX_X
{
  from y = 1 to MAX_Y
  {
    if(Abs(x / y - aspectRatio) <= epsilon)
    {
      return new Size(x, y);
    }
  }
}
return Size.Empty;
```

Comment: Why `Abs(..)`? The number is never negative...

Comment: Basically you want to find the smallest fraction for a decimal value (= smallest aspect ratio). I'm sure this is a GCSE maths problem but I can't actually remember how right now, lol

Comment: For starters I think your pseudo code is wrong unless I'm misunderstanding it, at no point does it refer to an aspect ratio value..

Comment: What you are doing, on second look, is finding a fraction that equals `0.001` (i.e., like x = 1 and y = 1000). But from your description, I'd say you have a ratio, say `3.8` and find the x and y that equal that ratio, i.e. x = 38 and y = 10 (assuming only integers are required), with a maximum deviation of `epsilon` (i.e., 38001 and 1000 is also a good answer). Is that correct? If so, one problem is that the deviation is not relative to the factors. It should rather be a percentage, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unusual.  You need to find the greatest common divisor and divide width and height by it.  The algorithm is by Euclid and is two thousand three hundred years old.  Details [are here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: The GCD of what values? The width and height?

Answer (score 1):

You can write aspectRatio as a **fraction** (if you want it up to a presicion of 0.001, than you can use round(aspectRatio,3)/1000 )

Then, [simplify this fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941048/how-to-simplify-fractions-in-csharp). The resulting fraction is the x/y you're looking for.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily get you the smallest result. For example, for `aspectRatio=0.3333333` you'll round to `333/1000` and can't simplify that. However, `1/3` is a better solution.

Comment: @steve - Yeah that's the problem I was running into when testing his idea.

Answer (score 1):

A quicker way, but still not formulaic would be to only look at possible y values instead of iterating up to MAX_Y.  e.g.:

```
    static Size FindMinSize(double requiredRatio, double epsilon)
    {
        int x = 1;
        do
        {
            int y = (int)(x * requiredRatio);
            if (Test(x, y, requiredRatio, epsilon))
            {
                return new Size(x, y);
            }

            y = (int)((x + 1) * requiredRatio);
            if (Test(x, y, requiredRatio, epsilon))
            {
                return new Size(x, y);
            }
            x++;
        } while (x != int.MaxValue);

        return new Size(0, 0);
    }

    static bool Test(int x, int y, double requiredRatio, double epsilon)
    {
        double aspectRatio = ((double)y)/x;
        return Math.Abs(aspectRatio - requiredRatio) < epsilon;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing all possible combinations, just increase the side that gets you closer to the aspect ratio:

```
public static Size GetSizeFromAspectRatio(double aspectRatio) {
  double epsilon = 0.001;
  int x = 1;
  int y = 1;
  while (true) {
    double a = (double)x / (double)y;
    if (Math.Abs(aspectRatio - a) < epsilon) break;
    if (a < aspectRatio) {
      x++;
    } else {
      y++;
    }
  }
  return new Size(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio is the ratio between x and y.  You can define the aspect ratio as x / y or y / x.

The minimum aspect ratio is 0 / 0.

Some other minimum has to be defined, either a minimum x or a minimum y.

min x = (min y * x) / y

min y = (min x * y) / x

Comment: I think the point you need to look for is that he wants the smallest whole integer numbers that produce the aspect ratio value (see `Size` used in question).

Comment: `0 / 0` looks like DivisionByZero to me ;)