# Is there a standard way to multiply fractions?

Tags: c#, fractions, multiplication

I need to have access to both denominator and numerator so I can't just multiply two Floats.
Should I write my own class and have operator overload (*) or are their known libraries that offer that?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2941154/659190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to write your own. [Here](http://www.vcskicks.com/code-snippet/fraction.php) is a link to a Fraction structure

Code from the link:

```
public struct Fraction
{
    public int Numerator;
    public int Denominator;
    public static Fraction Zero = new Fraction(0, 0);

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        this.Numerator = numerator;
        this.Denominator = denominator;

        //If denominator negative...
        if (this.Denominator < 0)
        {
            //...move the negative up to the numerator
            this.Numerator = -this.Numerator;
            this.Denominator = -this.Denominator;                        
        }
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, Fraction denominator)
    {
        //divide the numerator by the denominator fraction
        this = new Fraction(numerator, 1) / denominator;
    }

    public Fraction(Fraction numerator, int denominator)
    {
        //multiply the numerator fraction by 1 over the denominator
        this = numerator * new Fraction(1, denominator);
    }

    public Fraction(Fraction fraction)
    {
        this.Numerator = fraction.Numerator;
        this.Denominator = fraction.Denominator;
    }


    private static int getGCD(int a, int b)
    {
        //Drop negative signs
        a = Math.Abs(a);
        b = Math.Abs(b);

        //Return the greatest common denominator between two integers
        while (a != 0 && b != 0)
        {
            if (a > b)
                a %= b;
            else
                b %= a;
        }

        if (a == 0)
            return b;
        else
            return a;
    }

    private static int getLCD(int a, int b)
    {
        //Return the Least Common Denominator between two integers
        return (a * b) / getGCD(a, b);
    }


    public Fraction ToDenominator(int targetDenominator)
    {
        //Multiply the fraction by a factor to make the denominator
        //match the target denominator
        Fraction modifiedFraction = this;

        //Cannot reduce to smaller denominators
        if (targetDenominator < this.Denominator)
            return modifiedFraction;

        //The target denominator must be a factor of the current denominator
        if (targetDenominator % this.Denominator != 0)
            return modifiedFraction;

        if (this.Denominator != targetDenominator)
        {
            int factor = targetDenominator / this.Denominator;
            modifiedFraction.Denominator = targetDenominator;
            modifiedFraction.Numerator *= factor;
        }

        return modifiedFraction;
    }

    public Fraction GetReduced()
    {
        //Reduce the fraction to lowest terms
        Fraction modifiedFraction = this;

        //While the numerator and denominator share a greatest common denominator,
        //keep dividing both by it
        int gcd = 0;
        while (Math.Abs(gcd = getGCD(modifiedFraction.Numerator, modifiedFraction.Denominator)) != 1)
        {
            modifiedFraction.Numerator /= gcd;
            modifiedFraction.Denominator /= gcd;
        }

        //Make sure only a single negative sign is on the numerator
        if (modifiedFraction.Denominator < 0)
        {
            modifiedFraction.Numerator = -this.Numerator;
            modifiedFraction.Denominator = -this.Denominator;
        }

        return modifiedFraction;
    }

    public Fraction GetReciprocal()
    {
        //Flip the numerator and the denominator
        return new Fraction(this.Denominator, this.Numerator);
    }


    public static Fraction operator +(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        //Check if either fraction is zero
        if (fraction1.Denominator == 0)
            return fraction2;
        else if (fraction2.Denominator == 0)
            return fraction1;

        //Get Least Common Denominator
        int lcd = getLCD(fraction1.Denominator, fraction2.Denominator);

        //Transform the fractions
        fraction1 = fraction1.ToDenominator(lcd);
        fraction2 = fraction2.ToDenominator(lcd);

        //Return sum
        return new Fraction(fraction1.Numerator + fraction2.Numerator, lcd).GetReduced();
    }

    public static Fraction operator -(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        //Get Least Common Denominator
        int lcd = getLCD(fraction1.Denominator, fraction2.Denominator);

        //Transform the fractions
        fraction1 = fraction1.ToDenominator(lcd);
        fraction2 = fraction2.ToDenominator(lcd);

        //Return difference
        return new Fraction(fraction1.Numerator - fraction2.Numerator, lcd).GetReduced();
    }

    public static Fraction operator *(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        int numerator = fraction1.Numerator * fraction2.Numerator;
        int denomenator = fraction1.Denominator * fraction2.Denominator;

        return new Fraction(numerator, denomenator).GetReduced();
    }

    public static Fraction operator /(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
    {
        return new Fraction(fraction1 * fraction2.GetReciprocal()).GetReduced();
    }


    public double ToDouble()
    {
        return (double)this.Numerator / this.Denominator;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Numerator + "/" + Denominator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no ready classes in c# for that. Writing your own should be easy though. I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

defining a simple object would be a simple way to treat the problem.

```
public class Fraction
{
    decimal Denominator {get;set;}
    decimal Numerator {get;set;}

    public Fraction(decimal denum, decimal num)
    {
        Denominator = denum;
        Numearator = num;
    }
     //this way you can instantiate a fraction object with any value of your choice
}
```

After that just:
     Fraction f = new Fraction(5, 2);